# When using Google App Script to export a sheet to PDF, how do you specify a custom page/paper size?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When printing a sheet with the print dialog (CTRL+P) a custom page size can be used.
[image]

I'm using Google App script to generate PDFs. How do I set the page size to a custom size and specify the dimensions? This is the code I'm using:

```
var exportUrl = url_base + 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +
'&gid=' + sheetTabId + '&id=' + ssID +
'&range=' + range + 
'&size=A3' +  // paper size - How do I use a custom size and specify the dimensions?
'&scale=4' +
'&portrait=false' +
'&sheetnames=false' +
'&printtitle=false' +
'&pagenumbers=false' +
'&gridlines=false' +
'&fzr=false' +
'&top_margin=0.0' +
'&bottom_margin=0.0' +
'&left_margin=0.0' +
'&right_margin=0.0' +
'&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' +
'&vertical_alignment=MIDDLE';
```

There is a similar question here: [How to adjust as custom size margins and paper size in script to save google spreadsheet in PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334713/how-to-adjust-as-custom-size-margins-and-paper-size-in-script-to-save-google-spr), but the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question...

Answer (score 1):

```
'&size=AxB'
```

→ A = Width you gonna use (inch)
→ B = Height you gonna use (inch)

Note: Don't use mayus and space.
Note 2: Put both together with the "x".

Example:

```
'&size=2.8363636363x5.9055118110'
```

Equivalent to 7.2cm x 15cm

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72637309/11462274)