# Can we change default page size of PDF files created through GAS

Tags: pdf

this is my first encounter with you. I have a code which generates Invoices from google sheets. It picks Invoice no from a list provided & creates pdf invoices as per Invoice No. List.

My problem is that it creates bills always in Letter Page Size, however I want to get it in A5 Paper size.

I think its very easy for you expert friends. My Code is below

```
function PrintPDF(){
  
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    
  var shtSB = ss.getSheetByName("SALES-BILL");
  var shtSD = ss.getSheetByName("SALES-DATA");
  var LastRow = shtSD.getRange(5007,2).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  var sales = shtSD.getRange(5007,2,LastRow-1,2).getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0;i < sales.length;i++){

  shtSB.getRange("H8").setValue(sales[i][0]);
  var fileName = "SALES-BILL #" + sales[i][1] + "for" + sales[i][0]
  shtSD.hideSheet();

  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Sales Inv").next();
   
  var Blob = shtSB.getParent().getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');

     folder.createFile(Blob).setName(fileName);
  }
  shtSD.showSheet();
}
```

Comment: You mean to say that, we can't set page size to A5...in above code???

Comment: Friend I have to produce bulk invoices ..your suggestion is for limited nos. bills. Can you just modify my code to create pdf files in A5 paper size... If not possible for you then leave the matter for others to answer ..or you may forward to an expert.

Comment: I have already seen the link you shared . Can you embed it in my code ..so that it can work. ??

Comment: Is here any learned one to resolve the issue ??