# Server error when trying to save range of Google sheet cells to PDF in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code, running in Google Apps Script. The code attempts to take a range of a spreadsheet and save it as a PDF:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A586:K" + lastRow); 

// Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var pdfBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
pdfBlob.setName('test.pdf');


// Save the PDF to your Google Drive.
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1EJIzvW-oOnFfFOopiAAsudhbHsF5FGKz"); 
var file = folder.createFile(pdfBlob);
```

When I run the code, it runs for a while, then gives me the error:

```
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again
```

Any tips on what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to export the specific range of a sheet as a PDF format using Google Apps Script.

In your script, `range` is not used. And, the whole sheet is exported. In this case, I think that your goal can be achieved by the query parameter. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57334713) When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const folderId = "###";  // Please set your folder ID.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A586:K" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const startRow = range.getRow() - 1;
  const endRow = startRow + range.getNumRows();
  const startCol = range.getColumn() - 1;
  const endCol = startCol + range.getNumColumns();
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ss.getId()}/export?format=pdf&gid=${sheet.getSheetId()}&r1=${startRow}&c1=${startCol}&r2=${endRow}&c2=${endCol}`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  folder.createFile(res.getBlob().setName("sample.pdf"));
}
```

#### References:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- Related thread.

  - [How to adjust as custom size margins and paper size in script to save google spreadsheet in PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57334713)