# Export Google Sheets as PDF with custom setting

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I have a google sheet and I want to export it as a PDF with custom setting, such as:

```
size=6.29921x23.2283
portrait=true
fitw=true&source=labnol
sheetnames=false&printtitle=false
pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false
```

I'm using `from googleapiclient.discovery import build` and sending this request:

```py
serivices = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
serivices.files().export(fileId = google_sheet_id, mimeType = 'application/pdf').execute()
```

It's any way to add this setting to the request?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to export a Google Spreadsheet as a PDF file.
- When the Spreadsheet is converted to a PDF format, you want to inglude the following settings.

  ```
  size=6.29921x23.2283
  portrait=true
  fitw=true&source=labnol
  sheetnames=false&printtitle=false
  pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false
  ```

  - I guessed that the unit of `6.29921x23.2283` is inch.
- You are using googleapis for python. And `credentials` of `serivices = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)` can be used for downloading the Spreadsheet in PDF format.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this case, the access token is retrieved from your `credentials`. And, the endpoint is requested with the requests module.

#### Sample script:

```py
serivices = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials) # This is from your script.

# If your "creds" is from the service account, please enable the following line. If your "creds" is from OAuth2, please disable the following line.
# credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())

accessToken = credentials.token

outputFilename = "sample.pdf" # Please set the output filename.
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
q = {
    'format': 'pdf',
    'size': '6.29921x23.2283',
    'portrait': 'true',
    'fitw': 'true',
    'source': 'labnol',
    'sheetnames': 'false',
    'printtitle': 'false',
    'pagenumbers': 'false', # or 'pagenum': 'UNDEFINED',
    'gridlines': 'false'
}
queryParameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(q)
url = f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/export?{queryParameters}'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open(outputFilename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

- Please add the following import.

  ```py
  import urllib.parse
  import requests
  ```
- When this script is run, the Google Spreadsheet is exported as a PDF format by customizing with the values of `q`.
- About the comment line of `# credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())`, unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't know which you are using the OAuth2 or the service account. So, I proposed a script for both patterns. When this line is put as a comment, it is for the OAuth2. When this line is put as a script by removing `#`, it is for the service account. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Margins parameters for Google spreadsheet export as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46088042)
- [How to adjust as custom size margins and paper size in script to save google spreadsheet in PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57334713)
- https://gist.github.com/andrewroberts/c37d45619d5661cab078be2a3f2fd2bb
- https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70